# PostgreSQL - Psycopg2 - copy_from - Invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to insert bytes into my PostgreSQL (9.5.7) database column with the type `bytea`, using the Psycopg2 (2.7.1) copy_from() method.

I can insert my bytes with the following code :

```
psycopg2_cursor.copy_from(
    StringIO("\x30\x40\x50"),
    "my_table",
)
```

By executing a SELECT into my table after the insertion, I get the expected value from the bytea column:

`\x304050`

Now, I want to prepend my bytes with the byte 0:

```
psycopg2_cursor.copy_from(
    StringIO("\x00\x30\x40\x50"),
    "my_table",
)
```

I get the error : psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF-8": 0x00. From my understanding, this error should only be triggered when inserting a null byte into a text field, but should work as expected into a bytea field. Am I missing something ? Is there any simple way to insert a null byte into a bytea column ?

Thanks!

Comment: what's your `standard_conforming_strings` setting?

Comment: did you try `StringIO('\x30\x40\x50')` instead?..

Answer (score 2):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

> the following characters must be preceded by a backslash if they
>   appear as part of a column value: backslash itself, newline, carriage
>   return, and the current delimiter character.

just realized you are using `COPY`, so you have to escape backslash:

```
t=# copy b from stdin;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> \\x00
>> \.
COPY 1
t=# copy b from stdin;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> \x00
>> \.
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
CONTEXT:  COPY b, line 1: "\x00"
```

this should do the trick:

```
psycopg2_cursor.copy_from(
    StringIO("\\x00\\x30\\x40\\x50"),
    "my_table",
)
```

Comment: I added the following parameter to my psycopg2 connection : `options="-c standard_conforming_strings=on"`, but I still get the same error. I tried `StringIO('\x30\x40\x50')` and it works correctly, but I really need to insert this null byte. I tried to use a BytesIO instead of a StringIO, but I still get the same result.

Comment: try that? `select decode('00203040','hex')` - is it producing your wanted result?..

Comment: Yes, it produces the wanted result when using it in PSQL (`INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(decode('001060', 'hex'));`), but I need to insert my bytes with the copy_from() method from my python code, not directly with a SQL query.

Comment: last attempt: `psycopg2_cursor.copy_from(
    StringIO("\\x00\\x30\\x40\\x50"),
    "my_table",
)` ?..

Comment: Still the same (invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00). The good news is that I can insert bytes from my python code when using `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(decode('005566', 'hex'));")` but for performances issues (details on my github: https://github.com/jean553/massive-insert-postgresql-tornado), I would prefer to insert with `copy_from()`.

Comment: Thanks, I also had the problem with ora2pg when trying to migrate oracle product_media sample schema (PM). when importing the data with COPY command. Replacing the \x by \\x make it work !

Answer (score 1):

To insert a binary with `copy` it is necessary to use the [binary format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) which is not what you want. Use the [`extras.execute_values` method](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values)

```
from psycopg2.extensions import Binary

binaries = [[Binary('\x00\x20')], [Binary('\x00\x30')]]

insert_query = 'insert into t (b) values %s'
psycopg2.extras.execute_values (
    cursor, insert_query, binaries, page_size=100
)
```